# Will an DML process get affected if the application is upgraded or replaced at the same time?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

**Situation**

1. Oracle APEX (version not specified)
2. Single Application
3. Administration Issue: Deployment of New App version.

**Detail**

1. The latest version is on Server1
2. End Users are actively working on an older version hosted on Server2.
3. How do I import the changes made on Server1 without impacting users who may still be working on Server2?

Answer (score 1):

## Some Basics on Deploying APEX App Upgrades

It's always good etiquette to warn users that an upgrade will be in progress.  Give a few days advanced notice and a window of time you will need to accomplish the task.  In this case, as I will explain, you can install your new upgrade and switch over to the new version quickly.

### Use an Application Alias

Use an Application ALIAS to identify your application to get away from the arbitrary, sequence controlled ID.

**This is where to identify an APP ALIAS**
[image: How to Choose an APEX App Alias]

In this example, the Alias AND the ID can be used.  I recommend to publish the ALIAS to the users and the support staff who make the little shortcut icons on everyone's desktop:

```
    http://sakura.apex-server-01.guru:8080/apex/f?p=ALIAS
```

Where "ALIAS" is whatever you've assigned to the app (such as 'F_40788').  Aliases must be unique across an entire INSTANCE,  or you can set up some clever redirects using Oracle's RESTful Web Service builder.

### How to Switch Your Live Application to Maintenance Mode

The best way to avoid any unwanted DML or user activity from end users is to lock the front-end application right before you switch over to the new version.

This will prevent anything from changing the state of the data during the upgrade... in answer to the question, if a DML (insert, update, delete) activity initiates when the app is overwritten, either the transaction fails and rolls back because it didn't reach the COMMIT step.. or worse. You're better off just locking up for a few minutes.

**How to Set an Application to Maintenance Mode**
[image: Setting APEX Application Availability Mode]

Rename your `current version` to the permanent ALIAS and archiving the one it replaced. It's better not to overwrite or immediately delete your older versions.

**Multiple Versions Co-existing in the same Workspace:**

[image: Single APEX Workspace Organization]

It is equally as useful to check in the exported application definition scripts as they are encoded in UTF-8 plain text SQL.  The benefit is that source code diffs can identify the differences between ver

As long as their access is restricted, and their alias changed to a unlisted value, they serve as a good fallback for any unanticipated issues with the new, current release.

Comment: Thank You for your valuable answer Mr.Richard Pascual. I'll check with that.